# ASP.Net MVC Custom client side validation not firing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation, validationattribute

i have the below jquery unobtrusive code which is not firing.

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('customvalidation', ['productname'], function (options) {
    options.rules['customvalidation'] = { productname: options.params.productname };
});

$.validator.addMethod("customvalidation", function (value, element, param) {
    alert(param.productname);
    return false;
});
```

but the above code suppose to show alert i guess when pressing button to submit my form.

### here is my full code

### Model and view model

```
   public class Product
    {
        public int ID { set; get; }
        public string Name { set; get; }
    }

    public class Hobby 
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

    }

    public class SampleViewModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "Products")]
        public List<Product> Products { set; get; }

        //[AtleastOne(ErrorMessage = "Select at least one checkbox.")]
        public List<Hobby> Hobbies { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select any Product")]
        public int SelectedProductId { set; get; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select Male or Female")]
        public string Gender { get; set; }

        public bool? IsAdult { get; set; }
        public int? Age { get; set; }

        [ConditionalAttribute(SelectedProductID = "SelectedProductId", Products = "Products", Hobbies = "Hobbies",IsAdult="IsAdult",Age="Age")]
        public string ErrorMsg { get; set; }

    }
```

### Custom server side validation

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
    public class ConditionalAttribute : ValidationAttribute , IClientValidatable
    {
        public string SelectedProductID = "", Products = "", Hobbies="";
        public string IsAdult = "";
        public string Age ="";
        string _productname = "";
        bool _hashobby = false;
        bool _isadult = false;
        int _age = 0;

        public ConditionalAttribute() { }
        public ConditionalAttribute(string SelectedProductId, string Products, string Hobbies, string IsAdult, string Age)
        {
            this.SelectedProductID = SelectedProductId;
            this.Products = Products;
            this.Hobbies = Hobbies;
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            //getting selected product
            Product oProduct = null;
            ValidationResult validationResult = ValidationResult.Success;
            var containerType = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType();

            var SelectedProductID = containerType.GetProperty(this.SelectedProductID);
            Int32 selectedproduct = (Int32)SelectedProductID.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

            var ProductList = containerType.GetProperty(this.Products);
            List<Product> oProducts = (List<Product>)ProductList.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

            oProduct = oProducts.Where(e => e.ID == selectedproduct).FirstOrDefault();
            _productname = oProduct.Name;

            if (_productname != "iPod")
            {
                var field2 = containerType.GetProperty(this.Hobbies);
                List<Hobby> hobbies = (List<Hobby>)field2.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
                foreach (var hobby in hobbies)
                {
                    if (hobby.IsSelected)
                    {
                        _hashobby = true;
                        break;
                    }
                        //return ValidationResult.Success;
                }
                if (!_hashobby)
                {
                    this.ErrorMessage = "Select Any Hobbie's checkbox";
                    return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
                    //return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
                }
            }

            var PropIsAdult = containerType.GetProperty(this.IsAdult);
            if (PropIsAdult.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null) != null)
            {
                _isadult = (bool)PropIsAdult.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
                if (_isadult)
                {
                    var PropAge = containerType.GetProperty(this.Age);
                    if (PropAge.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null) != null)
                    {
                        _age = (Int32)PropAge.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
                        if (_age != null && _age <= 0)
                        {
                            this.ErrorMessage = "Age is compulsory for adult";
                            return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.ErrorMessage = "Age is compulsory for adult";
                        return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
            }
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }


        // Implement IClientValidatable for client side Validation
        public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
        {
            var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
            {
                ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName()),
                ValidationType = "customvalidation",
            };
            rule.ValidationParameters.Add("productname", _productname);
            yield return rule;
        }
    }
```

### My view code

```
@model  AuthTest.Models.SampleViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "TestVal", FormMethod.Post, new { name = "TestVal" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>DateValTest</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Products, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2", style = "padding-top:0px;" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedProductId, new SelectList(Model.Products, "ID", "Name"), "-- Select Product--")
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedProductId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Products.Count(); i++)
                {
                    <div>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Products[i].Name)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Products[i].ID)
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <b>Gender</b><br />
                <label>
                    <span>Male</span> @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Gender, "Male", new { style = "width:20px;" })
                    <span>Female</span>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Gender, "Female", new { style = "width:20px;" })
                </label>
                <label>
                </label>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gender, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10 input-validation-error">
                <b>Hobbies</b><br />
                @for (int x = 0; x < Model.Hobbies.Count(); x++)
                {
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(p => p.Hobbies[x].IsSelected, new { @class = "hobbycls",  id = "Hobbies" }) @: &nbsp; 
                    @Html.LabelFor(p => p.Hobbies[x].IsSelected, Model.Hobbies[x].Name) @: &nbsp;
                    @Html.HiddenFor(p => p.Hobbies[x].Name) 

                }
                <span id="Hobbies-error" class="field-validation-error">
                    <span>Select any hobbies.</span>
                </span>
            </div>

        </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <b>Is Adult</b><br />
                <label>
                    <span>Yes</span> @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsAdult, "true", new { style = "width:20px;" })
                    <span>No</span>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsAdult, "false", new { style = "width:20px;" })
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <label>
                    Enter Age @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Age)
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <label>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ErrorMsg) 
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ErrorMsg, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                @if (ViewBag.IsPostBack != null && ViewBag.IsPostBack)
                {
                    <text>
                    <b>Your Selected Product ID :</b> @ViewBag.ProductID<br />
                    <b>Your Selected Product Name :</b> @ViewBag.ProductName<br />
                    <b>Gender :</b> @ViewBag.Gender<br />
                    <b>Hobbies :</b> @ViewBag.Hobbies <br />
                    <b>Is Adult :</b> @ViewBag.IsAdult <br />
                    <b>Age :</b> @ViewBag.Age <br />
                    </text>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    <script type="text/javascript">

        //$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('customvalidation', ['productname', 'hashobby', 'isadult', 'age'], function (options) {
        $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('customvalidation', ['productname'], function (options) {
            options.rules['customvalidation'] = { productname: options.params.productname };
        });

        $.validator.addMethod("customvalidation", function (value, element, param) {
            alert(param.productname);
            return false;
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: The `$.validator` ignores hidden elements by default (your form control for property `ErrorMsg` is a hidden input) - refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33935671/attaching-jquery-validation-to-replacement-element/33937362#33937362)

Comment: if i decorate any other collection type property like this way

`[ConditionalAttribute(SelectedProductID = "SelectedProductId", Products = "Products", Hobbies = "Hobbies",IsAdult="IsAdult",Age="Age")]
public List<Hobby> Hobbies { get; set; }` then client side validation code will fire ?

Comment: I have no idea. I can't make any sense of the code in your attribute and that is certainly not how a validation attribute should be used. You apply a `ValidationAttribute` to a property to validate that property, not other properties in your model.

Comment: @StephenMuecke i am doing conditional validation suppose if my dropdown has selected value called 'xxx' then checkbox validation will fire. how to achieve this kind of task with custom validation? my server side validation is working but client side not.....looking for your suggestion if i need to alter any code.

Comment: What _checkbox validation_? The only checkboxes in your view are associated with you collection of Hobbies, and I have already told you that you cannot get client side validation with `jquery.validate` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive`. You need to write you own script.

Comment: @StephenMuecke one request can u plzz see one of my post....here is url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36306563/asp-net-mvc-how-to-supress-jquery-unobtrusive-client-side-validation-message-ba