# ASP.Net MVC: How to supress jquery unobtrusive client side validation message based on condition

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, unobtrusive-validation

see my code first.

### View and view model

```
public class SampleViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Products")]
    public List<Product> Products { set; get; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select Male or Female")]
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int ID { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
}
```

### controller code

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var SampleVM = new SampleViewModel();
    SampleVM.Products = new List<Product>
    {
    new Product{ ID=1, Name="IPhone" },
    new Product{ ID=2, Name="MacBook Pro" },
    new Product{ ID=3, Name="iPod" }           
    };
    return View(SampleVM);
}
```

### View code

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "TestVal", FormMethod.Post, new { name = "TestVal" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>DateValTest</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Products, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2", style = "padding-top:0px;" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedProductId, new SelectList(Model.Products, "ID", "Name"), "-- Select Product--")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedProductId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Products.Count(); i++)
            {
            <div>
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Products[i].Name)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Products[i].ID)
            </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <b>Gender</b><br />
            <label>
                <span>Male</span> @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Gender, "Male", new { style = "width:20px;" })
                <span>Female</span>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Gender, "Female", new { style = "width:20px;" })
            </label>
            <label>
            </label>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gender, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

so now tell me when i click on submit button without select gender radio button then validation message will appear but i want to suppress it and i want to show this validation message conditionally.

suppose product dropdown is showing 4 product say product1,product2....product4.

i want if user select product4 then gender radio button validation will not fire at client side else user has select any gender.

please guide me with sample code that what jquery code i need to plugin at client which will suppress gender validation message at client and some time will not suppress based on condition at the time of form submit.

looking for best guidance. thanks

Comment: Use a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIfNot]` or similar validation attribute

Comment: i roughly see the foolproof home page and do not understand how it would be possible to set rule with foolproof  that if product4 will be selected then validation will not fire for gender radio button otherwise will fire.......can u give me some idea.

Comment: Check this : Something similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17970584/conditional-validation-on-model-in-mvc

Comment: `[RequiredIfNot("SelectedProductId", "Product4")] public string Gender { get; set; }` (assuming the value of the option is `Product4`)

Comment: the idea will work for server side but i am looking for client side....share idea.

Comment: Using foolproof attributes do give client side validation!

Comment: i am looking for client side conditional validation by jquery validate plugin. please see my post and answer if possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36318962/how-to-perform-conditional-client-side-validation-by-jquery-validate-plugin

Comment: FGS. Using the foolproof `[RequiredIfNot]` attribute **WILL** give you client side validation.

Comment: @StephenMuecke can u post some code to handle my scenario with `foolproof [RequiredIfNot]` thanks

Comment: See my second comment.