# Jquery Unobstrusive validation : Array must contain 1 element

Tags: jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following viewmodel definition.My scenario is that array must contain atleast one item else error must be shown.

```
public class GroupVM
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter GroupName")]
    public string GroupName { get; set; }

    [RequiredArray(ErrorMessage="Please select Centre Code")]
    public int[] CentreCodeId { get; set; }
    public SelectList CentreCodeList { get; set; }

    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
}
```

I have performed the server side validation and its working fine,but client side validation is not working.

```
public class RequiredArray : ValidationAttribute,IClientValidatable
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var list = value as IList;
        if (list != null)
        {
            return list.Count > 0;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ValidationType = "emptyarray",
            ErrorMessage = this.ErrorMessage
        };            
        yield return rule;
    }
}
```

Client side script is as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("emptyarray", function (value, element, param) {
        if (element.value == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
    jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool("emptyarray");


})
```

Razor View is as follows

```
  @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.CentreCodeId
                        , Model.CentreCodeList
                        , new { @class = "form-control select2 courseList", @id = "ddlCentreCode" })
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CentreCodeId)
```

HTML Markup is as follows

```
<select class="form-control select2 courseList valid" data-val="true" data-val-emptyarray="Please select centre code" id="ddlCentreCode" multiple="multiple" name="CentreCodeId"><option value="5">NSTAJ001</option>
<option value="6">NSTVJ002</option>
<option value="7">NSNVY004</option>
<option value="8">NSTDJ005</option>
</select>
```

Any idea why the client side validation is not working.

Comment: Your `RequiredArray` class need to implement `IClientValidatable` (and it should be named `RequiredArrayAttribute` by convention)

Comment: Implemented  `IClientValidatable`.Still its not working.

Comment: What is the html generated by the ListBoxFor()` method (does it contain the `data-emptyarray` attribute). And why have you not included an error message?

Comment: Added HtmlMarkup for listbox.Error message is included(ErrorMessage = this.ErrorMessage).I think it should take error message from the `viewmodel` class.

Comment: No, you have shown the code for generating the view - you need to show the actual html that it generates (and yes, you have included the message - I didn't notice that in the model - although it probably should say _Please select at least one Centre Code_)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and I will look into it also I have updated the question(included html markup kindly check)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the surrounding `$(function () {` (the scripts just need to be inside `<script>` tags and after the `jquery.validate*` scripts, and you also need to check for and empty string, not `null`

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("emptyarray", function (value, element, param) {
        if (element.value === "") { // change
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
    jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool("emptyarray");
</script>
```

Side note: I am assuming `var list = value as IList;` is a typo (it would throw an exception) and its really `var list = value as IList<int>;`

Comment: Thanks for your support mate.Removing `document.ready function` does the trick here.I think manual client side validation via jquery is much better compared to this approach.

Comment: Not really. Then would only get client side validation, and would need to repeat the validation on the server (client side validation should only ever be considered a nice UI bonus - validation must always be performed on the server to protect against malicious users)

Comment: Yeah you are right.I meant server side validation + manual client side validation(instead of `creepy` adapter method)

Comment: What wrong with the adapter? If you were to implement it manually, you would then need to implement all the other features - lazy validation (initially on `.blur()`, but only if its changed, there after on `.keyup()`) and the code to display/remove the message as appropriate - if you look at the code in the `jquery.validate.js` file, there are about a dozen functions you need to make all this work correctly

Comment: Any way I have to use `keyup` function to remove the message since I am using `jquery select2` for list, and it does not removes the client side validation on selecting items by default.

Comment: Didn't notice that :) `select2` hides your `<select>` element and replaces it with its own html. By default, hidden inputs are not validated. Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33935671/attaching-jquery-validation-to-replacement-element/33937362#33937362) for how to override the default behavior

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link mate.