# I want validation from date is not greater than todate using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

### This Code is in view of MVC i take glyphicon calendar control in MVC.

```
<td>
    <div class='input-group date dt' onClick='datePick($(this));' data-val="true"
         data-val-required="Enter JourneyFDate" id='datetimepickerCar_0'>
        <input type='text' data-val="true" data-val-required="Describe skill!" name='car[0].Journey_FrmDate'
               id="txtdate" class='form-control textDecor nonEdit' placeholder="--Select Date--">

        <span class='input-group-addon'>
              <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-calendar'></span>
        </span>
        <span class='field-validation-valid' data-valmsg-for='car[0].Journey_FrmDate'
              data-valmsg-replace='true'></span>
    </div>
</td>
<td>
    <div class='input-group date dt' onClick='datePick($(this));' id='datetimepickerCar1_0'>
        <input type='text' data-val="true" data-val-required="Enter JourneyTDate" name='car[0].Journey_ToDate'
               id="txtdate1" class='form-control textDecor nonEdit' placeholder="--Select Date--">
        <span class='input-group-addon'>
              <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-calendar'></span>
        </span>
        <span class='field-validation-valid' data-valmsg-for='car[0].Journey_ToDate'
              data-valmsg-replace='true'></span>
    </div>       
</td>
```

The following code is j query code under script... how can i validate fromdate todate validation from date is not greater than todate please give me correct solution.

```
           $("#txtdate").keypress(function (event) { event.preventDefault(); });
$("#txtdate1").keypress(function (event) { event.preventDefault(); });

$(function () {
    $('#txtdate,#txtdate1').datetimepicker({
        useCurrent: false,
        minDate: moment()
    });
    $('#txtdate').datetimepicker().on('dp.change', function (e) {
        var incrementDay = moment(new Date(e.date));
        incrementDay.add(1, 'days');
        $('#txtdate1').data('DateTimePicker').minDate(incrementDay);
        $(this).data("DateTimePicker").hide();
    });

    $('#txtdate1').datetimepicker().on('dp.change', function (e) {
        var decrementDay = moment(new Date(e.date));
        decrementDay.subtract(1, 'days');
        $('#txtdate').data('DateTimePicker').maxDate(decrementDay);
        $(this).data("DateTimePicker").hide();
    });

});
```

Comment: I suggest you delete all that and use a conditional validation attribute so that you get client and server side validation out of the box, for example a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[GreaterThan]` attribute (or if you ant to write your own - [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)

Comment: This solution is working but its not showing validation message

Comment: Are you referring to your code, of using the foolproof attribute?

Comment: Yes Sir but i cant get message.

Comment: Yes what? Which code are you referring to?

Comment: [Required]
        [GreaterThanOrEqualTo("Journey_FrmDate", ErrorMessage = "Todate is greater than from date.")]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Journey_ToDate { get; set; }

Comment: Your using a jquery plugin for a datetimepicker. You have not indicated which one but it probably hides your textbox and adds its own html for it, in which case you need to reconfigure the `$validator` to validate hidden inputs as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33935671/attaching-jquery-validation-to-replacement-element/33937362#33937362)

Comment: If that is not you issue, then the code you tried is wrong (but I cannot see it)

Comment: This is in view page code

Comment: <td>
    <div class='input-group date dt' onClick='datePick($(this));' id='datetimepickerCar1_0'>
        <input type='text' data-val="true" data-val-required="Enter JourneyTDate" name='car[0].Journey_ToDate'
               id="txtdate1" class='form-control textDecor nonEdit' placeholder="--Select Date--">
        <span class='input-group-addon'>
              <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-calendar'></span>
        </span>
        <span class='field-validation-valid' data-valmsg-for='car[0].Journey_ToDate'
              data-valmsg-replace='true'></span>
    </div>       
</td>