# Is there a way to clear modelstate errors on the client?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a model with a list of child objects. I have created a custom validation attribute, implemented IValidatableObject on the model and i get an error message as expected. The problem is that once the property has an error in the modelstate, i can't get the updated value to post back to the server. They get cleared out some time between hitting the submit button and receiving the model in the controller.

if i call ModelState.Clear() in the controller action, i don't get any messages but the new values post as expected. The model is however picking up on the custom attribute because ModelState.IsValid == false

I'm thinking the best way to handle this is to call ModelState.Clear() on the client somehow after $(ready) so i get the validation messages but can also have the changed values post to the server. Is this possible or is there a better way to do this?

Parent Model

```
public class PayrollPlanModel : IMapFrom<Data.PayrollPlan>
{

    public int? PayrollPlanId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<PlanOptionFormModel> Options { get; set; }

}
```

Model List property on parent with custom attribute

```
public class PlanOptionFormModel : IValidatableObject
{
    public int PlanOptionValueId { get; set; }
    public int PayrollPlanId { get; set; }
    public string  PlanName { get; set; }
    public int PlanOptionId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [UIHint("_Money")]
    [RequiredIf("Selected", true)]
    public decimal? Value { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (Selected && !Value.HasValue)
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Add a value.");
        }
    }
}
```

Custom Attribute (Shamelessly stolen from here)

```
public class RequiredIfAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    RequiredAttribute _innerAttribute = new RequiredAttribute();
    public string _dependentProperty { get; set; }
    public object _targetValue { get; set; }

    public RequiredIfAttribute(string dependentProperty, object targetValue)
    {
        this._dependentProperty = dependentProperty;
        this._targetValue = targetValue;
    }
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var field = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(_dependentProperty);
        if (field != null)
        {
            var dependentValue = field.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
            if ((dependentValue == null && _targetValue == null) || (dependentValue.Equals(_targetValue)))
            {
                if (!_innerAttribute.IsValid(value))
                {
                    string name = validationContext.DisplayName;
                    return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage = name + " Is required.");
                }
            }
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
        else
        {
            return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(_dependentProperty));
        }
    }
}
```

Page snippet

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Options.Count; i++)
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Options[i].PlanOptionValueId)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Options[i].PayrollPlanId)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Options[i].PlanOptionId)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Options[i].Description)
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 text-right">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.Options[i].Selected, new { @data_textbox = "optionValue_" + i.ToString(), @class = "form-control modelOptionSelector" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-right">
            <h4>@Model.Options[i].Description</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.Options[i].Value, Model.Options[i].Selected ? new { HtmlAttributes = new { id = "optionValue_" + i.ToString(), @class = "planOptionValueEditor" } } : (object)new { HtmlAttributes = new { disabled = "disabled", id = "optionValue_" + i.ToString(), @class = "planOptionValueEditor" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Options[i].Value)
        </div>
    </div>
}
<br />
```

Editor Template

```
@model decimal?

@{
    var defaultHtmlAttributesObject = new { };
    var htmlAttributesObject = ViewData["htmlAttributes"] ?? new { };
    var htmlAttributes = Html.MergeHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributesObject, defaultHtmlAttributesObject);

    string attemptedValue = "";
    ModelState modelStateForValue = Html.ViewData.ModelState[Html.IdForModel().ToString()];
    if (modelStateForValue != null)
    {
        attemptedValue = modelStateForValue.Value.AttemptedValue;
    }

}

@(Html.Kendo().CurrencyTextBoxFor(m => m)
              .HtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes)
              .Format("c")
              .Spinners(false)
)
```

Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditPlan(PayrollPlanModel model)
    {

        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: `ModelState` is server side - it would be pointless to call it from the client. What you claiming does not make sense. Show your code and explain what the issue is.

Comment: i added the code. what about the issue dont you understand? once an error gets added to the view state that property will not post any updated values to the controller. im trying to think of a better way to explain it. gimme a minute

Comment: You do not seem to be understanding the difference between client and server side code for a start. And you should not be using `IValidatable` object (that will no give client side validation, not will your `RequiredIfAttribute` because you have not implement `IClientValidatable`. Give me a chance to try and understand what your trying to do based on your edit.

Comment: i understand them just fine. thanks. what i dont understand is why when a modelstate error gets added, the value stops posting to the server

Also not for nothing but once i implemented the interface, thats when the error messages started showing up on the client. shrugs

Comment: actually you may be right about the interface. the client side message is not the one returned on the client

Comment: With all respect, no you do not. Step 1. Remove the `IValidatableObject` interface from the `PlanOptionFormModel` model (and delete the `Validate()` method. Your `RequiredIfAttribute` is already doing that validation.

Comment: Step 2. Your `RequiredIfAttribute` needs to implement `IClientValidatable`, and your need to include the scripts for client side validation (refer [this GitHib project](https://github.com/stephenmuecke/mvc-conditionalvalidation) and for a good tutorial, refer [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)

Comment: i should edit. i was going to go that route but not sure i can install the required update on clients server

Comment: Step 3. I suspect your `CurrencyTextBoxFor()` hides the `<input>` and generates its own html. By default, hidden inputs are not validated so you need to reconfigure the validator- refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33935671/attaching-jquery-validation-to-replacement-element/33937362#33937362) for an example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167851/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-muckeypuck).

Comment: you helped me get this resolved. thanks alot. for those wondering, the answer is just say no to 3rd party controls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes no sense to attempt to attempt to clear `ModelState` errors from the client. `ModelState` is only set within the controller method (by the `DefaultModelBinder`) when you make a request to the method. In any case, your issues are not related to `ModelState` being valid or invalid in the controller method.

There are a number of changes you need to make to your code:

You should delete your `EditorTemplate` for `decimal?` It means that any property of that type is going to use that template. Instead replace your

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => Model.Options[i].Value, ...)
```

with

```
@(Html.Kendo().CurrencyTextBoxFor(m => m.Options[i].Value)....
```

in the main view.

If you really do want to use a template, then make it a named template (which is called using `@Html.EditorFor(m => Model.Options[i].Value, "yourTemplateName")`, but in any case, you need to remove the code relating to `attemptedValue` and `modelStateForValue` (including the `if` block) - the `EditorFor()` methods will always correctly use values from `ModelState` if they exist.

Next, your `RequiredIfAttribute` does not implement `IClientValidatable` so you will not get client side validation. You could use the [foolproof](https://github.com/leniel/foolproof) library, or if you want to write your own, refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49589458/client-side-validation-not-working-with-reused-and-nested-complex-property/49593553#49593553) for the full implementation of a `RequiredIfAttribute`, including the scripts for client side validation.

Next, you need to delete the `IValidatableObject` implementation (the `Validate()` method) from your model. That is just repeating the validation that the `[RequiredIf]` attribute is doing, and you should avoid mixing `ValidationAttribute`'s with `IValidatableObject` (refer [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2) for more detailed information).

Finally, the `Kendo().CurrencyTextBoxFor()` method hides the input and renders its own html. By default, hidden inputs are not validated, so you need to reconfigure the validator. In the main view, add the following script (after the `jquery-{version}.js`, `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` scripts

```
<script>
    $.validator.setDefaults({ 
        ignore: [] 
    });
    .... // other scripts as required
<script>
```