# Client side validation not working with reused and nested complex property

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-validation

I have an asp.net MVC 5 application in which I tried to re-use a nested complex view model class in different places in an `.cshtml` file. The reused complex view model is named as `SchoolPersonViewModel` that has many properties, and the `Phone` and `Email` properties are validated  like "If Phone is not provided, then Email must be provided. If Phone is provided, then Email is optional input". I wrote a custom server and client side validation but it works with server side. But the **client side validation** is not working properly. For example `Email` text box prompts to be filled even though the associated `Phone` text box is filled. Please see the attachment. For example.[image] Please help. Thank you beforehand.

I know the problem comes from the error: there are 3 validation attributes for the 3 Email text boxes with same value as `data-val-emailrequired-stringphoneprop="Phone"` . The `Phone` value at run time causes the ambiguity 
 (it is the uniqueness is missing) for the jQuery validation machine but I do not how to solve it. Please see the rendered attributes below. Please help. Thank you in advance.

***Details about my codes:***

On my `cshtml` view, I call the view model complex class (`SchoolPersonViewModel`) 3 times: one for `Student`, one for `Father` and one for `Mother`.

C# MVC model classes

```
public class SchoolPersonViewModel
{
    [DisplayName("Phone")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Email")]
    [EmailRequired(StringPhonePropertyName = "Phone", ErrorMessage = "Email is required if Phone is not provided")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    .... // other properties
}

public class StudentEnrollViewModel
{
    public SchoolPersonViewModel Student { get; set; }
    public SchoolPersonViewModel Father { get; set; }
    public SchoolPersonViewModel Mother { get; set; }
}
```

Validation attribute

```
// If Phone is not input then Email is required -- server and client side validation
public class EmailRequiredAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    public string StringPhonePropertyName { get; set; }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var phone = ValidatorCommon.GetValue<string>(validationContext.ObjectInstance, StringPhonePropertyName);
        var email = (string)value;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(phone) || (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(phone) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email)))
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(phone) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var modelClientValidationRule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ValidationType = "emailrequired",
            ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.DisplayName)
        };

        modelClientValidationRule.ValidationParameters.Add("stringphoneprop", StringPhonePropertyName);
        yield return modelClientValidationRule;
    }
}
```

Container view model and the jQuery validation codes:

```
@model ExpandoObjectSerializeDeserialize.Web.Models.StudentEnrollViewModel
....
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    ....
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Student)
    ....
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Father)
    ....
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Mother)

    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
}

@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery.validator.addMethod('emailrequired', function(value, element, params) {
            var phoneTextboxId = $(element).attr('data-val-emailrequired-stringphoneprop');
            var phoneTextboxValue = $('#' + phoneTextboxId).val();
            // empty string is evaluated as ‘false’ and non-empty, non-null string is evaluated as ‘true’ in JavaScript
            return phoneTextboxValue || value;
        });

        jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('emailrequired', {}, function(options) {
            options.rules['emailrequired'] = true;
            options.messages['emailrequired'] = options.message;
        });
    </script>
}
```

The above view is rendered as follows at running time:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Father_Phone" name="Father.Phone" type="text" value="">
    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Father.Phone" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <input class="form-control text-box single-line input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-emailrequired="Email is required if Phone is not provided" data-val-emailrequired-stringphoneprop="Phone" id="Student_Email" name="Student.Email" type="text" value="">
    <span class="text-danger field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="Student.Email" data-valmsg-replace="true"><span for="Student_Email" class="">Email is required if Phone is not provided</span></span>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Mother_Phone" name="Mother.Phone" type="text" value="">
    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Mother.Phone" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <input class="form-control text-box single-line input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-emailrequired="Email is required if Phone is not provided" data-val-emailrequired-stringphoneprop="Phone" id="Father_Email" name="Father.Email" type="text" value="">
    <span class="text-danger field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="Father.Email" data-valmsg-replace="true"><span for="Father_Email" class="">Email is required if Phone is not provided</span></span>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Mother_Phone" name="Mother.Phone" type="text" value="">
    <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Mother.Phone" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>      
<div class="col-md-4">
    <input class="form-control text-box single-line input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-emailrequired="Email is required if Phone is not provided" data-val-emailrequired-stringphoneprop="Phone" id="Mother_Email" name="Mother.Email" type="text" value="">
    <span class="text-danger field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="Mother.Email" data-valmsg-replace="true"><span for="Mother_Email" class="">Email is required if Phone is not provided</span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first poor design decision is that you have written a `ValidationAttribute` which is too specific to a particular scenario. Your attribute should be a simple `RequiredIfAttribute` that can be used in any scenario where the value of a property (not specifically your 'Email` property) is dependent on the value of another property.

In your case, the attribute would be used as

```
[RequiredIf("Phone", null, ErrorMessage = "...")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

The next issue you have is the client side script and the fact you do not get the value of the dependent property. Your

```
var phoneTextboxId = $(element).attr('data-val-emailrequired-stringphoneprop');
```

returns `"Phone"`, and therefore the following line

```
var phoneTextboxValue = $('#' + phoneTextboxId).val();
```

returns `undefined`, (the elements you want have `id="Father_Phone"` etc) which means that `return phoneTextboxValue || value;` always returns `false`.

[foolproof](https://github.com/leniel/foolproof) provides a library of many common conditional validation attributes, including a `[RequiredIf]` and a `[RequiredIfEmpty]`, both of which would be suitable for your case.

But if you want to write your own, then I recommend [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2) as a good guide.

The code for a `RequiredIfAttribute` would be

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class RequiredIfAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{

    #region .Declarations 

    private const string _DefaultErrorMessage = "Please enter the {0}.";
    private readonly string _PropertyName;
    private readonly object _Value;

    public RequiredIfAttribute(string propertyName, object value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyName");
        }
        _PropertyName = propertyName;
        _Value = value;
        ErrorMessage = _DefaultErrorMessage;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            var property = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType().GetProperty(_PropertyName);
            var propertyValue = property.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
            if (propertyValue != null && propertyValue.Equals(_Value))
            {
                return new ValidationResult(string.Format(ErrorMessageString, validationContext.DisplayName));
            }
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName()),
            ValidationType = "requiredif",
        };
        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("dependentproperty", _PropertyName);
        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("targetvalue", _Value);
        yield return rule;
    }
}
```

and the associated scripts

```
sandtrapValidation = {
    getDependentElement: function (validationElement, dependentProperty) {
        var dependentElement = $('#' + dependentProperty);
        if (dependentElement.length === 1) {
            return dependentElement;
        }
        var name = validationElement.name;
        var index = name.lastIndexOf(".") + 1;
        var id = (name.substr(0, index) + dependentProperty).replace(/[\.\[\]]/g, "_");
        dependentElement = $('#' + id);
        if (dependentElement.length === 1) {
            return dependentElement;
        }
        // Try using the name attribute
        name = (name.substr(0, index) + dependentProperty);
        dependentElement = $('[name="' + name + '"]');
        if (dependentElement.length > 0) {
            return dependentElement.first();
        }
        return null;
    }
}

$.validator.addMethod("requiredif", function (value, element, params) {
    if ($(element).val() != '') {
        // The element has a value so its OK
        return true;
    }
    if (!params.dependentelement) {
        return true;
    }
    var dependentElement = $(params.dependentelement);
    if (dependentElement.is(':checkbox')) {
        var dependentValue = dependentElement.is(':checked') ? 'True' : 'False';
        return dependentValue != params.targetvalue;
    } else if (dependentElement.is(':radio')) {
        // If its a radio button, we cannot rely on the id attribute
        // So use the name attribute to get the value of the checked radio button
        var dependentName = dependentElement[0].name;
        dependentValue = $('input[name="' + dependentName + '"]:checked').val();
        return dependentValue != params.targetvalue;
    }
    return dependentElement.val() !== params.targetvalue;
});

$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("requiredif", ["dependentproperty", "targetvalue"], function (options) {
    var element = options.element;
    var dependentproperty = options.params.dependentproperty;
    var dependentElement = sandtrapValidation.getDependentElement(element, dependentproperty);
    options.rules['requiredif'] = {
        dependentelement: dependentElement,
        targetvalue: options.params.targetvalue
    };
    options.messages['requiredif'] = options.message;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. By the way, I would like to know under which circumstances, the name attribute of html tag (element) is built with character [ or ] in it?   I understand the dot (.) character with my code example.  Your JavaScript code line: var id = (name.substr(0, index) + dependentProperty).replace(/[\.\[\]]/g, "_");  is used regular expression to extract wanted sub-string.

Comment: Its generated for collections. For example a `@for(int i = 0; i < Model.MyCollection.MyProperty.Count; i++) { @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyCollection[i].MyProperty)` generates `<input name=MyCollection[0].MyProperty" id="MyCollection_0__MyProperty" ... />`