# How to display child records in form after ModelState.IsValid is False?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, model, edit

I am using RequiredIf attribute: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/dotvvm-build-conditional-validation-attribute/

It works as expected when creating a new record. However, when editing an existing record, ModelState.IsValid is set to false if two fields that are required if a certain project type drop-down value is selected are null.

Because of this, two issues happen:

1. Any child records that were previously displayed in their respective tables in the form are no longer displayed.
2. The record number is displayed as zero. This is not the record Id.

When the record is saved, the child records and the correct record number (not zero) are displayed in the details page.

This is my code: [image: Validation Code]

Comment: I do not understand why the solution above does not work as follows: 1. A certain project type drop-down value is selected. 2. The selection of that certain project type drop-down value activates the RequiredIf condition. 3. The two required fields are left blank. 4. The user clicks the Save button. 5. The user is informed that the two required fields cannot be null. Instead, it looks like the ModelState is being checked to see if it is valid. Because of this, the two issues that I previously mentioned are encountered.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that client side validation was not being performed.

I used the following URL resource to implement the solution: [Client side validation not working with reused and nested complex property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49589458/client-side-validation-not-working-with-reused-and-nested-complex-property)