# Display validation message for a hidden input field in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I added a file upload field to an ASP.Net form. As the field is required, I added 
a validation message and everything worked fine. After that, I wanted to customize the file input style like this:

**Code:**

```
<div class="input-group">
    <label class="input-group-btn">
        <span class="btn btn-success">
            National ID photo&hellip;@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NationalIDPhoto, new {
                @Type = "file", @Id = "ifile-national-id", @Class = "hidden"
            })
        </span>
    </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly>
</div>
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NationalIDPhoto, "", new {
    @Class = "text-danger"
})
```

And here is `model.NationalIDPhoto` attribute declaration

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    /*
     * Other attributes here
     */
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "National ID Photo")]
    public HttpPostedFileWrapper NationalIDPhoto { get; set; }
    /*
     * And more attributes there
     */
 }
```

**Output 1:**
[image]
**Problem:**
The validation message does not appear. After some research and trials, I got the reason.

**Reason:** `@Class = "hidden"` causes both the input field and the associated validation message to be hidden. That is, either both are hidden or both are visible.

When I removed `@Class = "hidden"`, the output looked like that

**Output 2:**
[image]

According to that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33937362/7280140), I tried the following script, but it didn't work:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ 
    ignore: [] 
});
```

How can I show the validation message for the hidden field ?

Comment: The script does work! I can only assume you have not located it correctly (must be after `jquery.validate.js` and not in `$(document.ready)`

Comment: Oh, thank you very much. It worked now