# How to validate the file's size with jquery-validation-unobtrusive in ASP.NET MVC 5 project?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have a web project that is written using c# on the top of ASP.NET MVC 5 framework. I am using `jquery-validation-unobtrusive` package to establish a client-side validation. I am trying to add a new rule called `filesize` which inspects the size of the attached file.

So when the attached file's size is greater than the allowed, I want to show client size error message.

I created [FileSizeAttribute](https://github.com/CrestApps/MvcWithUnobtrusive/blob/master/MvcWithUnobtrusive/FileSizeAttribute.cs) attribute to be able to use in my view-models to decorate my `HttpPostedFileBase` properties with to set the max allowed size. The [CreatePerson](https://github.com/CrestApps/MvcWithUnobtrusive/blob/master/MvcWithUnobtrusive/ViewModels/CreatePerson.cs) class show how I am consuming it.

Then in my javascript files, I added the following code to register a new method called [filesize](https://github.com/CrestApps/MvcWithUnobtrusive/blob/master/MvcWithUnobtrusive/Scripts/jquery.validate.setup.js#L32-L58) in the [jquery-validator](https://jqueryvalidation.org/).

Model

```
[Required, FileSize(4000), AcceptedFileExtension("jpg|pdf|csv|text")]
public HttpPostedFileBase Picture { get; set; }
```

View

```
<div class="form-group" id="Picture_Block">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Picture">Picture</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="input-group uploaded-file-group max-input-width">
            <label class="input-group-btn">
                <span class="btn btn-default">
                    Browse 
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Picture, new { @class= "hidden force-validaion", type = "file" })
                </span>
            </label>
            <input class="form-control uploaded-file-name" readonly="" type="text">
        </div>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Picture)
    </div>
</div>
```

Validation scripts

```
$.validator.addMethod("filesize", function (value, element, param) {
    if (value === "") {
        return true;
    }
    var maxBytes = parseInt(param);
    if (element.files !== undefined && element.files[0] !== undefined && element.files[0].size !== undefined) {
        console.log('Dumping the file object', element.files[0]);
        var filesize = parseInt(element.files[0].size);
        return filesize <= maxBytes;
    }
    return true;
});
```

Then I added a new unobtrusive adapter called [filesize](https://github.com/CrestApps/MvcWithUnobtrusive/blob/master/MvcWithUnobtrusive/Scripts/jquery.validate.setup.js#L60-L74) to allow me to add the rule/message to the validation options like so

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('filesize', ['maxfilesize'], function (options) {
    // set the parameter
    options.rules['filesize'] = options.params.maxfilesize;
    if (options.message) {
        // If there is a message, set it for the rule
        options.messages['filesize'] = options.message;
    }
});
```

I can see the the adapter is being registered, but the method [filesize](https://github.com/CrestApps/MvcWithUnobtrusive/blob/master/MvcWithUnobtrusive/Scripts/jquery.validate.setup.js#L32-L58) is not being called.

I am expecting to show an error message when the user upload exceeds the set file-size however it is not being called when the file is attached.

I create a repository to show how the `$.validator.addMethod("filesize", function (value, element, param)` is not being called which can be download from [MvcWithUnobtrusive](https://github.com/CrestApps/MvcWithUnobtrusive)

What I am doing wrong here? How can I register the `filesize` method with `$.validator`?

Comment: Please don't create a new tag called `jquery-validate-unobtrusive` when a tag already exists to cover this plugin called `unobtrusive-validation`.

Comment: You have a simple typo in `console.log('Dumping the file object', lement.files[0]);` which cause your script to fail - its `element.files[0]`

Comment: As a side note, do not combine multiple validation conditions in a single attribute. You should have a separate `FileTypeAttribute` (refer [How to validate file type of HttpPostedFileBase attribute in Asp.Net MVC 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40199870/how-to-validate-file-type-of-httppostedfilebase-attribute-in-asp-net-mvc-4/40200034#40200034) for an example)

Comment: @StephenMuecke sorry that typo is fixed locally but I forgot to publish that on GitHub. That typo did not solve the problem. Additionally, I actually have a separate attribute for validation the type.

Comment: I tested you code and it works fine :)

Comment: Note that those scripts should not be wrapped in `$(document).ready()` in case you have done that

Comment: Just had a look at your repo. You have a hidden input for `Picture` - hidden inputs are not validated by default (but you can override the validator to include them - refer [attaching jquery validation to replacement element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33935671/attaching-jquery-validation-to-replacement-element/33937362#33937362) for an example)

Comment: @StephenMuecke that was indeed the problem. The `Picture` was ignored because it was hidden. If you post an answer I would gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file input for `Picture` is hidden, and by default, hidden inputs are not validated.

Your can override the default by including the following script

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ 
    ignore: [] 
});
```

or if you have other hidden elements that you don't want validated, then you could give the element a class name (say `class="fileinput"`) and use

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ 
    ignore: ":hidden:not('.fileinput')"
});
```